# How to convert a permutation to permutation polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, permutations

Let $\mathbf{F}_q$ be the finite field with $q$ elements, where $q$ is a prime power.
A permutation on $\mathbf{F}_q$ is a bijection from $\mathbf{F}_q$ to itself.
Let $\mathbf{F}_q$ be the ring of polynomials in a single indeterminate $x$ over $\mathbf{F}_q$.
A polynomial $f \in \mathbf{F}_q[x]$ is called a permutation polynomial of $\mathbf{F}_q$ if it induces a one-to-one map from $\mathbf{F}_q$ to itself.
It is well known that every permutation on $\mathbf{F}_q$ can be expressed as a
permutation polynomial over $\mathbf{F}_q$.

Problem 1: How to convert a permutation to a permutation polynomial? Please note that Lagrange polynomial as polynomial interpolation is possible. Any other method?

Problem 2: as problem (1) but with $\mathbf{F}_q$ and $q$ composite (not a prime).

Comment: How do you mean problem 2? If $q$ is not prime power, what does $F_q$ denote? The ring $\Bbb Z/q\Bbb Z$?

Comment: Yes, Fq as a ring Z/qZ.
Example: F6 like Z6. Of course, some elements have no multiplicative inverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can just use the fact that $1-(x-a)^{q-1}$ is the indicator function of the point $a$, so the formula $\sum \sigma(a)\cdot(1-(x-a)^{q-1})$ will do.
Generally, constructing permutation polynomials is a complicated problem. There is a chapter on the subject in Lidl, Niederreiter finite fields. There are a lot of papers on the subject, e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.2229 . The answer, of course,  depends on the general form of resulting formula that you want.

I don't see why any permutation is a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Lets take any permutation that moves $2$ to $0$ and $0$ to $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. The corresponding polynomial must have its last coefficient both odd and even.

Comment: Even if coefficient degree zero is 0 (permute 0 --> 0), i did not found a general solution. This is what I wanted to confirm with you all. Seems like the statement:

"every permutation on Fq can be expressed as a permutation polynomial over Fq"

is incorrect for Z/nZ with composite n. 
*Some* permutations *can be* expressed as a permutation polynomial over Z/nZ, but some are not.

Comment: For $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ it is actually interesting, what functions can be represented by polynomials. If nothing comes to mind in a few days will ask here ))